# Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() redirection on register does not work

Tags: php, laravel

I have this on my controller but the redirection does not work it says Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login(), I have tried this so far but nothing

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Events\NewUserWasRegistered;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Validator;
use Auth;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $rules = [
                'email'                => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'password'             => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
                'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
                'allow_register'       => 'required|accepted',
            ];

        if (app()->environment('local') || app()->environment('testing')) {
            unset($rules['g-recaptcha-response']);
        }

        $data['allow_register'] = config('root.app.allow_register', true);

        $messages = [
            'allow_register.accepted' => trans('app.allow_register'),
        ];

        return Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     *
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $user = User::create([
            'username' => md5("{$data['name']}/{$data['email']}"),
            'name'     => $data['name'],
            'email'    => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'role_id'     => $data['role'],

        ]);


        event(new NewUserWasRegistered($user));
          if($user){

                if ($user->role_id == 0) {

                   Auth::login($user);
                    return redirect('user/businesses');


                }else if($user->role_id == 1){

                    Auth::login($user);
                    return 'Working on..';
                }
            }

        // return $user;
    } 
}
```

Can someone please help me I am stuck, I have tried so many things but I am new on coding so maybe you will understand If it is that I am asking too much

Answer (score 0):

`App\Models\User` **must** implement the interface/contract `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`.

> "If you need to log an existing user instance into your application, you may call the `login` method with the user instance. The given object must be an implementation of the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` contract. Of course, the `App\User` model included with Laravel already implements this interface ..."
>
> [Laravel 5.7 Docs - Authentication - Manually Authenticating Users - Other Authentication Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#other-authentication-methods)

Side Note:

The `create` method of that controller is **only** for taking an array of data and creating a new User and returning that User instance. Nothing else. The `registration` flow out of the box calls that method, only to create the user. It then does the login and everything else.